# get anchor has been clicked among multiple anchors have the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php loop that prints an anchor multiple times :

```
<div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop action-buttons">
    <a class="red" href="#" id="d_id" data-value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <i class="icon-trash bigger-130" id="bootbox-confirm"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

and I have this JQuery code to get the link that has been clicked :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#d_id").on(ace.click_event, function() {
                var x = $(this).attr('data-value');
                bootbox.confirm(x, function(result) {
                    if(result) {
                        bootbox.alert(x);
                    }
                });
            });
       })
    </script>
```

this work only for the first anchor

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique in your document.  Once jQuery has found an element with that `id` it will stop looking. If you want to reference multiple items you should use a `class` instead.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Per jQuery documentation: Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

Comment: thanks guys , but I change id attribute to class and still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the id's for classes since id's are ment to be unique and for this reason the first element with that id will be the only taken into account by jquery:

```
<div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop action-buttons">
    <a class="red d_id" href="#" data-value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <i class="icon-trash bigger-130" id="bootbox-confirm"></i>
    </a>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".d_id").on(ace.click_event, function() {
            var x = $(this).attr('data-value');
            bootbox.confirm(x, function(result) {
                if(result) {
                    bootbox.alert(x);
                }
            });
        });
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple divs with the same id, change it to class, and on the click event selector, go for a '.d_id'.

Also, using $(this) gets you the element which was actually clicked, this means that 'this' can be the icon element you have there, instead of the one you want.

So you can do something like:

```
$("#d_id").on(ace.click_event, function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('data-value');
    if (typeof x === 'undefined'){
        x = $(this).parent().attr('data-value');
    }
    ...
});
```

Something like this :-)

Comment: thank you buddy , the previous solution worked fine :)